# Why do I keep getting a list index out of range error in my code?

Tags: python

Here is my csv file:

```
dan, 12pts
```

Here is the code and I keep getting an index out of range error in my code? I don't understand what's wrong with it:

```
import csv

with open('scoreboard.csv','r') as csv_file:
   csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

   for line in csv_reader:
       print(line[1])
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try `print(repr(line))` before `print(line[1])` to see what the problematic line is.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite possibly due to a blank line in your file, such that there is no second element.  To diagnose this, instrument your code with a little extra reporting:

```
import csv

with open('scoreboard.csv','r') as csv_file:
   csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

   for line in csv_reader:
       print(line)
       print(len(line))
       print(line[1])
```

This will show you what's going wrong, *just* before it blows up.

Answer (score 0):

You have a blank line after the first line in your csv file.

Reproducing your error with appending a blank line after your first row 
(Note: "<" characters are not the part of the csv file):

```
< dan, 12pts
<
```

we get the error message of course:

```
import csv

with open('scoreboard.txt','r') as csv_file:
   csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

   for line in csv_reader:
       print(line[1])
```

**Out:**

```
print(line[1])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

For first sight the blank line in a csv file can hide pritty well, but after we delete it (or them!):

```
< dan, 12pts
```

**Out:**

```
12pts
```